# Count If match multiple fields: First field by initials, second field if date has been filled

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to create a simple tracker. In columns B and C, tasks are tagged with an author, and then the author fills in a completion date.

Above is a dashboard that counts items for easy viewing. I countif for the total, but have not been able write a formula for the complete column. I've tried countifs, but haven't been able to get the formula to work.

Thoughts?

[image: SO15530769 example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula as per attached

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using DSUM will probably send you in the right direction.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/dsum-HP005209069.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your image, you should do a Pivot table for your dashboard.

If you absoluteley have to (???) get along without a Pivot table, do the following:

- start the dashboard in column B, so that column A just contains column header "Tasks" and data (no blank rows allowed!)
- count the number of tasks as `=COUNTA(A:A)-1` (-1 for the header)
- count all other columns as `=COUNTA(OFFSET(B5;0;0;$E$2;1))` (in this example you count column B, header is in B4, first data therefore in in B5, number in tasks from above formula in $E$2)

The Offset function basically gives back a range starting relative to a reference and being of chooseable size. So we start it at the first data cell and make it 1 column wide, and #oftasks rows deep

Answer (score 0):

With COUNTIFS, assuming VH is in `A8`, Tasks/Author/Completed are in Row12 and you have or might have data up to Row1000:

`=COUNTIFS(B$12:B$1000,A8,C$12:C$1000,">1")`

copied down as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *SUMPRODUCT* to find the amount completed per author.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$8:$B$16=A3),--($C$8:$C$16>1))
```

In this case, the "--" tells *SUMPRODUCT* to treat each cell in the array (I used the example by User2063626) individually so it starts at the beginning and checks if B8=VH and records the answer as a boolean (1 for TRUE or 0 for FALSE), in this case it does equal VH so it uses a 1. Then it checks to see if C8>1 (it will be if there is a date) and stores a 1. It then multiplies the two values together 1*1=1 to give you a value for the first row. It then moves on and does the check for B9 (gets a 1 because it is equal to VH) and C9 (gets a 0 because there is no date), multiplies the row result 1*0=0 and adds it to the previous result. It repeats for each row in the array and returns the count of rows where the author was VH AND there is a completed date (2).